# show that $y^2 = x^5 - x +2 $ has no integer solutions

Tags: elementary-number-theory, solution-verification, modular-arithmetic

I considered everything$\mod 3$:

$x,y \equiv 0 \mod 3 ,\;\;\;\; y^2 \equiv 0 \mod 3 ,\;\;\;\; x^5 \equiv 0 \equiv x \mod 3$
$x,y \equiv 1 \mod 3 ,\;\;\;\; y^2 \equiv 1 \mod 3 ,\;\;\;\; x^5 \equiv 1 \equiv x \mod 3$
$x,y \equiv 2 \mod 3 ,\;\;\;\; y^2 \equiv 1 \mod 3 ,\;\;\;\; x^5 \equiv 2 \equiv x \mod 3$

thus in particular $x^5 - x \equiv 0 \mod 3, \;\;\; \forall x \in \mathbb{Z},$ and furthermore
$x^5 - x + 2 \equiv 2 \mod 3, \;\;\; \forall x \in \mathbb{Z}$.

But, $y^2 \equiv 0,1 \mod 3$, and if we were considering that there would be an integer solution then both sides should have the same remainder modulo $3$, but LHS and RHS never have the same remainder thus there are no integer solutions?

This is my first time doing a proof of this form, I'm familiar with modular arithmetic, however I've never used it to prove that a polynomial equation didn't have integer solutions.

Comment: Why are you unsure of the correctness of your argument?

Comment: I've never done a proof like this before, I'm a little insecure about the whole left hand right hand side getting different remainders leading to there being no integer solutions... or at least I'm having trouble picturing it

Comment: related https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c3h1614068p10086292

Comment: @Albus yes thank you

Comment: Think about the equation $2m = 4n + 3$. Are you concerned about this having no solution in integers because the left side is even ($0 \bmod 2$) and the right side is odd ($1 \bmod 2$) no matter what integers you use for $m$ and $n$?  If not, then this mod $3$ argument is the same idea in a fancier setting.  My only further comment is that a more "natural" modulus to use in this problem is $5$ rather than $3$, although the conclusion will still be the same.

Comment: @KCd thank you for the clarification

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your reasoning is correct.

Here a similar way using [little Fermat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem) for $p=5$:

$$x^5\equiv x \mod 5$$

Hence,

$$y^2\equiv 2 \mod 5$$

but the quadratic residues $\mod 5$ are $0,1,4$.

So, no solution in integers exists.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use $\bmod 3$:

$$y^2-2=x(x^2-1)(x^2+1)$$

RHS: $x^2-1\equiv 0\bmod 3\Rightarrow RHS \equiv 0\bmod 3$

But :

LHS: $$y^2-1-1\equiv (0\bmod 3-1\bmod 3)\equiv -1\bmod 3$$